# Customize existing theme on visual studio code

Tags: visual-studio-code

I'm going crazy here trying to figure out how to customize the token colors in my vs code editor. I'm using the "Material Theme Lighter High Contrast" but I want to change the color of the "Type" tokens. So I changed my `settings.json` file to include the following:

```
"editor.tokenColorCustomizations": {
    "[Atom One Dark]": {
        "comments": "#a2ffe3d8"
    },
    "[Material Theme Lighter High Contrast]": {
        "functions": "#00ff4c"
    }
},
```

After changing the settings I go to reload my window and for a couple of seconds I can see the color change to the new setting but then it goes right back to the awful yellow. Any ideas what's going on?

Comment: Ok wait I just figured something out. If I disable Enhanced Colorization in the c++ intellisense extension, then everything works. Weird?? Why is this?? I would like to keep the enhanced colorization on if possible??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you everyone for all the help. After hours of spending way too much time trying to figure out this theme stuff instead of working on my actual project, I have finally figured out the problem. When you use enhanced colorization you can't use the normal token types. See here for more info https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/colorization-cpp